# Jmeter -Load testing of an API in chunks

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmx, jmeter-plugins, web-api-testing

I want to test the load where I need to pass data in chunks.

Instead of passing complete load at once, first 200 records in first call after few seconds in second call next 200 records and so on

Comment: What do you have so far? Where are your Problems? There are more details needed.

Comment: This could be achieved through timers. Did you give it a try with https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer or https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer.

Comment: Did my answer helped? did you succeeded using jmeter plugin ? https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
[Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) JMeter plugin to achieve such goal

Using rows with different delays as:

[image]